# Checking if SQL array contains DropDownList Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net DropDownList which pulls its information from a SQL View.  Through another SELECT query I am populating a `List` with `branchID's` from the table.  Then I want to see if this List contains the same value as `branchDDL.SelectedValue`.  I have the below code in a `submit button click event`:

```
List<int> branches;
while (reader1.Read())
{
    branches = (from IDataRecord r in reader1 select (int)r["branchID"]).ToList();
}

if (branches.Contains(branchDDL.SelectedValue))
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

The issue is that this won't work.  The if check says it has some invalid arguments.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having here is that you're comparing `string` values to `integers`, making `Equals()` return false.

As the [MSDN page specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using the **default equality comparer**.

In your code, `Equals` is called with a `string` on the one side and an `int` on the other side, which will never be equal. Try parsing your `SelectedValue` into an integer and compare them afterwards; it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information.  That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (branches.Contains(Int32.Parse(branchDDL.SelectedValue)))
```

The selected value is a string, but you're populating the list with ints